# Why do mobile ads fail?

Tags: usability, mobile, user-behavior

I want to know from a UX perspective putting aside the fact that the time at which the ad is displayed is never right. Lately I've been noticing various formats to try and engage a user (me in some cases) but users don't even glance it. I do get some relevant ads that I used to download an app. On the whole experience front why do our finds just shut off when we see an ad?

Comment: It's an interruption, a distraction, a pesky fly getting in the way. Speaking for myself.

Comment: When you wrote "Why do our *f*inds just shut off" I think you meant *m*inds—but the M is so far from the F on my keyboard, I'm reluctant to edit this for you. :o

Answer (score 2):

Think about the user's tasks. They're using the app for a particular purpose, working toward certain goals. Ads are, therefore, distractions or hurdles in the way of reaching those goals.

You might also be interested in reading about [Banner Blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_blindness).